# Cluto like library for Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, cluto

I like Cluto as a data clustering software a lot. But its library binding is available only in C.

Is there any python library which is similar to Cluto?

Comment: About how many data points do you have, in 2d 3d 10d 128d, how many clusters ?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried any of them, but there are a few things which say they do clustering in Python:

- [scipy.cluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) (numpy and scipy are the two mainstays of serious numerical computation in Python)
- [Pycluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html)
- [hcluster](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hcluster/0.2.0) (looks like it's not been updated in a couple of years)

If none of those do the trick, you could use something like [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to call functions from Cluto, although it won't be as elegant.

Comment: scipy.cluster is pretty good, I've used it (google "scipy.cluster" => many hits, with site:stackoverflow.com too). Pycluster is I believe designed for low-dimensional gene clusters. hcluster seems to be an extinct scipy.cluster, also by Damian Eads.